# Reference for "Auszug aus einem Briefe von L. Kronecker an R. Dedekind"

Tags: mathematicians, reference-request

While I was looking for a source about Kronecker's Jugendtraum, I found [this](http://www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/5667300) document: Auszug aus einem Briefe von L. Kronecker an R. Dedekind vom 15. März 1880.

The bottom of the given page has a note: Jacobi, Werke, Bd. 1, S. 266. I found [this](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k90209g/f279.image), but it contains apparently no information about this letter from Kronecker to Dedekind. Does anyone know how this reference to Jacobi's works should be understood?

Moreover, we have only here an "Auszug" (= excerpt) of the letter. Is the full version available anywhere?

Thank you!

Comment: This could be relevant: http://www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/5927533 ; [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=UzTBBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA57&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) we can read "One of Frobenius’ first duties as Kronecker’s successor had been to write, in 1893, the memorial essay on the life and work of the late Kronecker for the Berlin Academy of Sciences [202]. Dedekind wrote to Frobenius to suggest that a letter he had received from Kronecker in 1880 was of sufficient mathematical interest to warrant publication in the proceedings of the academy.)"

Comment: See also https://books.google.com/books?id=3-1n8-BQIUYC&pg=PA277, appendix LIV.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a general problem with numbers here. The footnote 2) that links to Jacobi just is the reference for the paper cited in the letter, near the bottom of the page. The footnote numbered 1) is the one you need, which references "Zusatz 35" at the end of the volume. However what they probably meant was "Zusatz 34" (p. 510-515), as this is a longer note about the letter and the Jugendtraum.

Also there is a title page for the letter (p. 453), which gives the "Sitzungsberichte der Königlich Preussischen Akademie der Wissenschaften zu Berlin" as a source. However this seems to be the same excerpt.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, the reference [here](http://bibliothek.bbaw.de/bbaw/bibliothek-digital/digitalequellen/schriften/anzeige/index_html?band=10-sitz/1895-1&seite:int=129) gives the same excerpt, but with the indication "vorgelegt von Hrn. Frobenius" (presented by Mr. Frobenius).